# How do I use Struts-menu in Struts project?

Tags: struts

I am using [Struts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Struts) for my college of engineering project. I am creating a main page. For that I want Struts-menu for creating a menu, but I didn't find any tutorial for the same. What site can be recommended or how can I otherwise do it?

Answer (score 1):

- See the [**User Guide**](http://struts-menu.sourceforge.net/userguide.html)
- Run **[struts-menu-2.4.3.war](http://sourceforge.net/projects/struts-menu/files/Struts%20Menu%202.x/2.4.3/struts-menu-2.4.3.war/download)** in Tomcat and learn. (same with [**Struts-menu demo**](http://demo.raibledesigns.com/struts-menu/index.jsp))